# Возможно ли поменять имя учетного запись и имени компьютера в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Если возможно, то каким образом?
Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Два раза прочитал, но так и не смог вычленить из этого несогласованного набора слов что же именно нужно сделать

Comment: извините что не складно набрал наборов слов... дело в том что у меня в терминале слишком длинная имя и с дефисом получился... поздно понял, теперь я хочу по короче переименовать. Ну типа, vladimir-vladimir@Zotac-Zbox-Nano в vldf@zbox

Comment: Поправить хост `/etc/hostname`. Поправить логин - сначала `man usermod`, читать до ключа `--login`, потом править.

Comment: /etc/hostname  в терминале набирать? или как нужно поправить?

Comment: текстовым редактором)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя пользователя меняется в `/etc/passwd` и `/etc/shadow`.

Имя помпьютера меняется в `/etc/hostname` и `/etc/hosts`.

Это текстовые файлы и правятся редактором. Будте с ними аккуратны.

```
sudo gedit /etc/passwd /etc/shadow /etc/hostname /etc/hosts
```

Обрати внимание что домашняя папка должна существовать по казанному пути или не сможешь войти в систему. Лучше оставить её старой.

Имя компьютер можно поменять через программу `hostnamectl`, а логин через `usermod`.

Comment: в терминале пишет что "отказано в доступе". Как быть?

Comment: получить права =)

Comment: sudo usermod -l ah1 ahon
user ahon is currently used by process 1726

Пишет: регистрация пользователя в настоящее время используется процессом 1726 

По-моему проще оставить как и есть. А то смотрю уж совсем сложно получается )))

Comment: потому и предложил сразу поправь в тексте..)